# FFmpeg filter for selecting video/audio streams

Tags: c, filter, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a node (a collection of nodes is fine too), that takes in many streams and an index, and outputs one stream specified by the index. Basically, I want to create a mux node, something like:

```
Node : Stream ... Number -> Stream
```

FFmpeg's filter graph API seems to have two filters for doing that: `streamselect` (for video) and `astreamselect` (for audio). And for the most part, they seem to do what I want:

```
[in0][in1][in2]streamselect=inputs=3:map=1[out]
```

This stream will take in three video streams, and output the second one `in1`.

You can use a similar filter for audio streams:

```
[in0][in1]astreamselect=inputs=2:map=0[out]
```

Which will take in two streams and output the first one `in0`.

The question is, can I create a filter that takes in a list of both audio and video streams and outputs the stream based only on the stream index? So something like:

```
[v0][v1][a0][a1][a2]avstreamselect=inputs=5:map=3[out]
```

Which maps `a1` to `out`?

If it helps I am using the libavfilter C API rather than the command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be possible with one filter<sup>1</sup>, it is certainly possible to do this by combining multiple filters, one for either audio or video (depending on which one you are selecting), and a bunch of `nullsink` or `anullsink` filters for the rest of them.

For example, the would be filter:

```
[v0][v1][a0][a1]avstreamselect=inputs=4:map=2[out]
```

which takes in two video streams and two audio streams, and returns the third stream (the first audio stream), can be written as:

```
[a0][a1]astreamselect=inputs=2:map=0[out];
[v0]nullsink;[v1]nullsink
```

Here, we run select for the first stream, and all of the remaining ones are mapped to sinks. This idea could potentially be generalized to only use `nullsink`, `anullsink`, `copy`, and `acopy`, for example, we could have also written it with 4 nodes:

```
[a0]acopy[out];
[a1]anullsink;
[v0]nullsink;
[v1]nullsink
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>I still don't know if it is or not. Feel free to remove this if it actually is possible.</sub>